# Is it possible to create a custom alert tone for WhatsApp on iOS?

Tags: ios, whatsapp.app

I know it's possible to use a custom ringtone as an alert tone for certain notifications (like text messages and reminders).  However, this doesn't work with WhatsApp, since the app only allows you to choose from alert tones and not ringtones.  So, is there any way to save an audio file as an alert tone so that I can use a custom notification for WhatsApp?

Comment: We need an answers for this. Is this possible to do?

Comment: @Nip, I never got an answer and was unable to find any solution anywhere else online. I wish I could help!